# Custom vector data drawing

Tags: leaflet, software-recommendations, vectorization, streets

I'm trying to create a map for a fictional map. I'm using Leaflet to display the map, with tiles, different levels of zoom and so on.

Now I need to generate, to "draw", some vector data. Specifically, I have streets that I need to add to the map.

Is there any software where I can do something like "draw" those streets as a vector and export them to use in a JS file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use http://geojson.io/ to create vector points, lines, or polygons with attached properties (attributes) and save them to geojson format (or a few other formats), which you can use in Leaflet or another web mapping library.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you "draw" the vector-data in QGIS and the export the map from QGIS by the qgis2web-plugin(export to leaflet availible)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use the [geoman.io](https://geoman.io/geojson-editor) which works at the same basis as geojson.io.

[image]